# Change background-image on checking checkbox Jquery?

Tags: jquery, checkbox, background-image

I'm trying to change the background image on body, I have transparent and solid patterns images and have this code:

```
$('#patterns, #solid').click(function() {           
    var pattern = $(this).val();                    
    if ($('input:checkbox').is(':checked')) {
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url("images/patterns/solid/'+ pattern +'.png")'); 
    } 
    else {
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url("images/patterns/'+ pattern +'.png")');
    }           
});
```

I have in the html one select with option values for the transparent patterns, and also a checkbox that says Check this checkbox if you want to use the solid patterns. Thanks a lot.

```
<label for="pattern">Choose Pattern</label>
        <select id="patterns" name="pattern">
            <option value="absurdidad">absurdidad</option>
            <option value="arches">arches</option>
            <option value="argyle">argyle</option>
            <option value="batthern">batthern</option>
        </select>

        <label for="solid">Use only solid patterns</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="solid" />
```

If I put the css('background-color', 'red'); } else { css('background-color', 'black') }; Works like a charm, on click immediately fires and changes the background color, keeps the transparent pattern and adds the background-color, but not the background-image

Comment: Try using css classes and then use the methods `.addClass` and `.removeClass`...

Comment: Using css classes for images will take a lot time, want to keep it simple, what if I have 100 images x 2 = 200... I see no point for using classes

Comment: @cula Is the path to the background image correct?

Comment: @Russ Ferri Yes it is, checked it before implementing the ckeckbox, also it does change the bg images but first have to check the box than to select from dropdown...I want on click immedetly to change the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method call `$(this).val()` is returning the value of the checkbox. From your html snippet, the pattern should be the value of the option selected in the combobox.

---

If I'm understanding correctly, this should accomplish what you are looking for:

```
// Update the background image on the body tag when:
//   a) A new pattern is selected, or
//   b) The solid checkbox is checked or unchecked
$('#patterns, #solid').change(function() {  
    var pattern,
        isSolid;

    // Get the pattern from the value selected in #patterns.    
    pattern = $('#patterns option:selected').val();

    // Use a solid background if #solid is checked.
    isSolid = $('#solid').is(':checked');

    if (isSolid) {
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url("images/patterns/solid/'+ pattern +'.png")');  
    } else {
        $('body').css('background-image', 'url("images/patterns/'+ pattern +'.png")');
    }
});
```

Comment: you rule, it works as a charm, just on the first click gives me blank (just the bg color) and after I change to other pattern gives me correct and later if I uncheck gives me the transparent pattern again which is good, just the first checkin gives me nothing just the bg color, like deletes it. and thank you all for participating and givin me answers.

Comment: @cula Awesome, happy to help! Please accept the most helpful answer when you are satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#patterns').on('change', function() {
    var pattern = $(this).val(),
        url;
    if ($('#solid').is(':checked')) {
        url = "images/patterns/solid/" + pattern + ".png";
    } 
    else {
        url = "images/patterns/" + pattern + ".png";
    }           
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + url + ')');
}).trigger('change');
$('#solid').click(function() {
    $('#patterns').trigger('change');
});
```

If that works then it should simplify to :

```
var $patterns = $('#patterns').on('change', function() {
    var str = $solid.is(':checked') ? 'solid/' : '';
    $('body').css('background-image', 'url(images/patterns/' + str + $(this).val() + '.png)');
}).trigger('change');
var $solid = $('#solid').click(function() {
    $patterns.trigger('change');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Working demo** to change image on the click of checkbox: http://jsfiddle.net/FWNTQ/

**code**

```
$('#checkboxID').click(function() {
    var newImg = new Image;
    newImg.onload = function() {

        $('#myimage').attr('src', this.src).removeClass('loading');
        $('#container .loader').hide();
    }
    $('#container .loader').show();
    $('#myimage').addClass('loading');
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        newImg.src = 'http://images4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20111016234902/maditsmadfunny/images/thumb/5/54/Hulk-from-the-movie.jpg/180px-Hulk-from-the-movie.jpg';
    } else {
        newImg.src = 'http://www.hybrideb.com/content/evidence/doubletree.png';
    }

});
```

**css**

```
#container .loader{
    position:absolute;
    left:50px;
    top:50px;
    z-index:999;
    display:none;
}
#container{
    position:relative;
}
.loading{
 opacity:.5;
}
```